# wamp 500 internal error after enabling rewrite module

Tags: apache, wamp, wampserver

After installing [WampServer](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) on windows, I tried to access my web site but I faced this message :

[image]

So I enabled the mod-rewrite by going in the menu Apache → Apache modules → rewrite_module. But now I face this error message :

[image]

Here is the apache_error file :

```
[Sat Oct 24 16:51:02.884800 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 3244:tid 392] AH00422: Parent: Received shutdown signal -- Shutting down the server.
[Sat Oct 24 16:51:04.912800 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 2940:tid 308] AH00364: Child: All worker threads have exited.
[Sat Oct 24 16:51:04.928400 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 3244:tid 392] AH00430: Parent: Child process 2940 exited successfully.
[Sat Oct 24 16:51:05.646000 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4104:tid 396] AH00455: Apache/2.4.9 (Win32) PHP/5.5.12 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sat Oct 24 16:51:05.646000 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4104:tid 396] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC11 Server built: Mar 16 2014 12:13:13
[Sat Oct 24 16:51:05.646000 2015] [core:notice] [pid 4104:tid 396] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\\wamp\\bin\\apache\\apache2.4.9\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.9'
[Sat Oct 24 16:51:05.661600 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4104:tid 396] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 4184
[Sat Oct 24 16:51:06.160800 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4184:tid 312] AH00354: Child: Starting 64 worker threads.
```

I tried to make a virtual host and an alias, but it didn't resolve anything. I found different forum and people talking about a .htaccess file but I don't know if it is related to my problem.

I would like to know what is throwing this error and how to resole it.

Edit 1 :

In the apache error log I found this error :

```
AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
```

After some research, I think this could be due to some rules in the .htaccess file.

Here is my .htaccess file :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule  ^$ public/    [L]
    RewriteRule  (.*) public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: First thing you always should do with errors in that environment is to take a look into your http servers error log file.

Comment: And a side note: it helps to keep the wording clear, that way it is easier to understand each other: there is not such thing as a "wamp server". A server is a process answering to requests. "wamp" is not a server, but a nick name for a MS-Windows system running an apache http server, a mysql database server and the php scripting language.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out my mistakes. I will make anything that can help the comprehension of everyone.

Comment: So what did you find in that error log file?

Comment: @arkascha WAMPServer is in fact a specific instance of a WAMP stack see [Their web site](http://www.wampserver.com/?lang=en) Thats why there is a tag called `wampserver`

Comment: It looks like you have changed more than what you have mentioned i.e. port 8080. There is no reason why `mod_rewrite` should cause this error on its own. I suggest you start from a clean install of WAMPServer. Then change one thing at a time, check everything still works before moving on to the next change

Comment: @RiggsFolly Certainly it is an instance, but nevertheless the term "server" is missused in there. That does not depend on who writes it.

Comment: Well that normally means that your `.htaccess` is wrong.